# WPF ComboBox - Get Newly SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selectionchanged

In WPF, with the JComboBox and having a SelectionChanged="myComboBox_SelectionChanged" field in the xaml, how do you get the string for the *newly* selected item?  The code below shows the string for the *previously* selected item.

```
private void myComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
     var comboBox = (sender as ComboBox);
     Console.WriteLine(comboBox.Text);  //prints out PREVIOUSLY selected item
}
```

Comment: Did you ever bother to take a look at the online documentation? You might have noticed the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` properties.

Comment: @Clemens yes i did.  did you actually read my question?  you would have seen where I went wrong. try to be less rude. we are not all c# gods

Comment: Of course I've read the question. But the problem is just too trivial. When you are able to add a `SelectionChanged` handler, it is virtually impossible to miss a `SelectedItem` property. Even without online documentation you simply had to take a look at what IntelliSense offers.

Comment: i had SelectedItem in my code. i did not think it was relevant to the question. my question was why comboBox.Text returns the previously selected item opposted to the newly selected item.

Comment: That's simply because Text changes *after* the SelectionChanged event fires. The `Text` property is not the right thing to look for when you want to get the selected item. There are however the `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` properties that may help you to get a string value from the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Try the AddedItems property on the event args. This gets a list that contains the items that were selected:

```
    private void myComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        IList items = args.AddedItems;
        object firstSelecteditem = items[0];
    }
```